# fullcalendar events overlapping in month view in IE

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

My Calendar works fine but the events (different time events) are not displayed properly in Internet Explorer. Attaching images.
Firefox:
http://i.imgur.com/1v3D4VN.png
Internet Explorer:
http://i.imgur.com/maMFctM.png

Any idea what's the issue with IE?

Comment: Use the developer tools to see whether the positions are absolute or relative for each of the events on a date

Comment: Position is absolute. But how does it render properly in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Override the styles for each of the event element as `position:relative` and `width:100%`

Hope this helps you

Comment: Changing the width doesn't work. I guess I need to change the top property. Events are overlapped.

Comment: @sanket I know that because of absolute positioning, the divs are overlapping. Due to which you need to set it relative and for each element set width as 100%

Comment: Replaced with new version and it got fixed. Thanks anyways.